# property declared Public in code-behind is reported as undeclared on aspx page

Tags: asp.net

None of the public properties in code-behind is visible on the page:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' >
    var a = <%= foo1 %>;
    var b = <%= foo2 %>;
    var c = <%= foo3 %>; 
</script>
```

All are reported as not declared, possibly due to protection level. But all are properly declared in code behind:

```
 private _foo as String = ""

 Public Property Foo2 As String
        Get
            Return _foo
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
          _foo = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

This is legacy code which has been working for years. Not sure why all of a sudden these properties are not visible on the aspx page.

The page declaration hasn't changed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: does the error as not exist in current context?

Comment: This legacy code is VB.  If it were C#, yes, it would display the error message you give.  In VB it is "not declared".

Comment: given code is working in vb with changes in declaration as var a = '<%= foo1 %>';  (single quotes around variable).